# Could the Kelpie exist?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology, evolution, mythical-creatures

Residing in Scotland, the [Kelpie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelpie) is a creature of Celtic folklore being depicted as:

- looking like a black horse
- residing in lakes and pools
- lure in humans which they then drown and likely eat (optional)
- have a mane which resembles seaweed

Given these characteristics, what species could the Kelpie have evolved from, and what evolutionary pressures would lead to such a creature?

NOTE: magic does not exist in my story

Comment: Please, if you are following the anatomically correct series, stitch to the related standard.

Comment: VTC: poor quality, as it's a copy-paste of other questions. Make this about your world or make it of use & interest to others! Always ask yourself: *what is the worldbuilding problem I need to solve?* before posting a query!

Comment: @elemtilas again i don't see how this breaks any of the AC rules and are you just going to go on a crusade against all my AC questions?

Comment: Please come and participate in the [ACS discussion](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7842/should-we-narrow-down-the-scope-of-the-anatomically-correct-series)!  Since a lot of your questions are being questioned, I think your input will be most valuable!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Possible - it's a pinniped**

It's not horse-based, that's for sure. For one, horses are vegetarians, so shifting them to a meat-based diet not really so easy. So, if we're looking for a quadruped (or, at least quadruped-like) animal that can live in water, we're looking at a pinniped variant. Pinniped is a family of mammals which primarily include the various seal families, although it also includes sea lion and walruses.

Now, if you changed the profile to give your seal-like animal stronger flippers and adjusted the head a little bit, it could easily look like a black horse rising from the water, it would be fine eating human meat, and you wouldn't even need to have it naturally develop a 'seaweed mane' - that's just seaweed which snapped onto it.

Comment: A seaweed like mane could have adapted as a camouflage mechanism so they can ambush prey on the shore line.

Answer (score 4):

It's a hippo.

A big black horse-like creature that resides in pools, extremely territorial? Sounds to me like the very rare Celtic hippo. It runs underwater and lives in lake. It would explain the kelpie's kill count too - hippos are extremely dangerous creatures when disturbed. It doesn't eat them but it most certainly drowns anyone who comes near.

Mind, the 'mane that resembles seaweed' doesn't quite fit, but it's not too implausible that some hippo-variant might have a mane. There's no real practical reason for a hippo to have a mane, but it could be a trait that was evolved for sexual attraction. Or maybe their 'mane' is actual seaweed - the hippos bath in Scottish lakes and they get seaweed on them.